# Ubuntu freezes for 2 seconds when I click 6 or more keys

Tags: freeze, 21.10

It doesn't matter if I have any programs open or closed, Ubuntu always freezes once 6 or more keys are pressed at the same time.
I'm running an Intel 5 2500k, GT 1030, 16gb of ddr3 ram, and 480gb ssd. I'm using a fresh Ubuntu 21.10 and there isn't any overheating in my computer.
I haven't tried anything yet because I can't find any answer related to this issue. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Do you have the Nvidia drivers installed and running?

Comment: Yes I do have them installed and running

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting your PC, if that doesn't work, try the website I have linked: https://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/common-reasons-for-ubuntu-crashes-and-how-to-recover/ and if that does not work, it may be system files are missing or the keyboard sensor (if you type keys they print on your screen). To check so, here are instructions to help you:

Power on or reboot your machine through the GUI or by using the terminal: sudo reboot.
Press and hold the shift key during boot-up.
Select Advanced options for Ubuntu.
Then, select the entry with (recovery mode) at the end.
Select fsck from the menu.

Comment: Hey mate I tried rebooting my computer and din't work so I tried entering these "Advance options for Ubuntu" but when I hold shift my motherboard logo stays on screen and doesn't disappear so the computer can boot until I stop holding shift. I have tried searching some questions and answers and I have fortunaly found some but only problem I can't understand what I should do

Comment: Hmm, maybe try resetting your OS?